# Display items in a queue

Tags: c#

I have created a simple Windows form application which allows a user to insert `names` and removes `names` from a `queue`.

I have created all the methods required, but I want all the items inside the queue to be displayed each time the `Add` and `Remove` button is clicked.

Currently my code only displays the `head` of the queue when using `.Peek()`.

Please see image below:

[image: My windows form application]

**Queue class code**

```
class Queue
    {
        private readonly int maxsize = 10;
        private string[] store;
        private int head = 0;
        private int tail = 0;
        private int numItems;

        public Queue()
        {
            store = new string[maxsize];
        }

        public Queue(int size)
        {
            maxsize = size;
            store = new string[maxsize];
        }

        public void Enqueue(string value)
        {
            numItems++;
            store[tail] = value;
            if (++tail == maxsize)
            {
                tail = 0;
            }
        }

        public string Dequeue()
        {
            string headItem;
            //numItems--;
            headItem = store[head];
            if (headItem != null)
            {
                store[head] = null;
                numItems--;
                if (++head == maxsize)
                    head = 0;
            }

            return headItem;

        }

        public bool IsEmpty()
        {
            return tail == 0; //returns the boolean result of the comparison between head and 0
        }

        public bool IsFull()
        {
            return tail == maxsize;
        }
        public int CountQueue() //counts the number of items inside the queue
        {
            return tail - head;
        }

        public int Tail //property
        {
            set { this.tail = value; }
            get { return tail; }
        }

        public int Head //property
        {
            set { this.head = value; }
            get { return head; }
        }

        public string Peek()
        {
            return store[head];
        }

    }
```

**Form Code**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Queue names = new Queue();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            names.Enqueue(NameTextBox.Text);
            CountLabel.Text = "Number of entries: " +  Convert.ToString(names.CountQueue());

            if (names.CountQueue() > 0)
            {
                DisplayLabel.Text = names.Peek();
            }
            else
                DisplayLabel.Text = "No names entered";

        }

        private void RemoveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            names.Dequeue();
            if (names.CountQueue() == 0)
                CountLabel.Text = "Queue is empty";

            else
                CountLabel.Text = "Number of entries: " + Convert.ToString(names.CountQueue());

            if (names.CountQueue() > 0)
            {
                DisplayLabel.Text = names.Peek();
            }
            else
                DisplayLabel.Text = "No names entered";


        }
    }
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using the `System.Collections.Generic.Queue` class? It implements `IEnumerable<T>`, which makes it really easy to show the items.

Comment: You could just add a `public string[] GetAllItems` method that returns a copy of `store`...

Answer (score 0):

For clarity, are you asking how to display the full queue?
If so, you would be better off using a Listbox instead of a label to display names, and every time a name is added, you just say something like

```
lstNames.Items.Add(names.Peek());
```

after you add a name, lstNames being the Listbox instance. Then, when you decide to remove an item from the queue, say something like

```
lstNames.Items.RemoveAt(0);
```

Hope that helps, sorry if I misunderstood the question.

Edit: Not sure if you edited your question or I just misread it, but it's clear to me what you were asking for now.

Edit2: Sorry, I meant lstNames.Items.Add(NameTextBox.Text), not names.peek()!

Comment: Yes I'm trying to display the full queue. I'm trying to implement your code: ```lstName.add(names.Peek());``` but the ```.add()``` doesn't seem to be working, it doesn't show on intellisense

Comment: I tried using your answer, but when testing it, it keeps displaying the first name entered each time I enter a different name. For example: first name: John, Second name: Mike, Third name: David. But the list keeps prints 3 copies of John

Comment: Ah, I've made a mistake! Instead of names.Peek() in the Add() call, just put the name name. You can use lstNames.Items.Add(NameTextBox.Text) before you clear the textbox.